# yii2: get records by relations id

Tags: activerecord, relational-database, yii2, junction-table

I have Images model with relation:

```
public function getAlbums()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ImagesTerms::className(), ['id' => 'term_id'])
                ->viaTable(ImagesTermsRelations::tableName(), ['object_id' => 'id'])
                ->andWhere(['type'=>'album']);
}
```

On image view page I want to show random images with the same albums. Can anyone help?

I tried with the following query, but it didn't gave me what I want:

```
$related = Images::find()->with([
        'albums' => function($query) {
            $query->andWhere(['in', 'id', [2]]);
        }
])->where(['status'=>'1'])->orderBy('rand()')->limit(9)->all();
```

This query excludes other albums, but not images. Images with other albums are shown, but without album tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
$related = Images::find()->joinWith([
    'albums' => function($query) {
        $query->andWhere(['in', 'images_terms.id', [1,2,3]);
    }
])->where(['images.status'=>'1'])->orderBy('rand()')->limit(9)->all();
```